# EnumSet of bit flags into UInt in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, bit-manipulation, enumset

I have a lot of `enum class` in my Kotlin application. They all represent bit flags that I need to convert between `EnumSet<>` and `UInt` for serial communication with an FPGA board.

How can I provide some extension methods that apply to all those Enums?

Enums don't allow class inheritance. EnumSet can't reference an interface. I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks!

```
enum class ReadFlag(val bits: UInt) {
  DATA_READY(1u)
  BUSY(2u)
}

typealias ReadFlags = EnumSet<ReadFlag>

enum class WriteFlag(val bits: UInt) {
  UART_RESET(1u)
  BUSY(2u)
  PAGE_DATA(4u)
}

typealias WriteFlags = EnumSet<WriteFlag>

fun ReadFlags.asUInt(): UInt =
    this.fold(0u) { acc, next -> acc or next.bits }

fun WriteFlags.asUInt(): UInt =
    this.fold(0u) { acc, next -> acc or next.bits }
```

This results in this error:

```
error: platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (asUInt(Ljava/util/EnumSet;)I):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write an interface for the common members:

```
interface Flags {
    val bits: UInt
}
```

Implement the interface:

```
enum class ReadFlag(override val bits: UInt): Flags {
    DATA_READY(1u),
    BUSY(2u)
}

enum class WriteFlag(override val bits: UInt): Flags {
    UART_RESET(1u),
    BUSY(2u),
    PAGE_DATA(4u)
}
```

Then you can make your `asUInt` generic:

```
fun <E> EnumSet<E>.asUInt(): UInt where E : Enum<E>, E: Flags =
    this.fold(0u) { acc, next -> acc or next.bits }
```